# applying the central limit theorem to estimate the probability

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose the time in days until a component fails has the gamma distribution with 
alpha = 5, and theta = 1/10.
When a component fails, it is immediately replaced by a new component. 
Use the central limit theorem to estimate the probability that 40 components will together be sufficient to last at least 6 years.
*Assume that a year has 365.25 days

This is a homework question.

Answer (score 2):

**Outline:**

(1) Compute or look up the mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ of your particular instance of the gamma distribution.

(2) The length of time $T$ that $40$ components last is given by $T=X_1+X_2+\cdots X_{40}$, where the $X_i$ are independent gamma of the type described in the question.

(3) The random variable $T$ has mean $40\mu$ and variance $40\sigma^2$.

(4) If we cross our fingers, then $T$, being a sum of a not too small number of resonably nice iid random variables, has a "close to normal" distribution.

(5) Find the probability that a normally distributed random variable  with mean $40\mu$ and variance $40\sigma^2$ is greater than $(6)(365.25)$.

Comment: Nicolas: Each gamma variable can also be written as a sum of iid exponential random variables.

Comment: Since the parameter is an integer, that is definitely a nicer way of doing it. Ultimately OP would has to make the same calculation in either case, apart from skipping step 1.